# Py2exe + nibabel

Tags: python, py2exe

When I try to launch the application (.exe) file created by [p2toexe](http://www.py2exe.org/), I receive the following error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_GUI.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "nibabel\__init__.pyc", line 38, in <module>
  File "nibabel\analyze.pyc", line 87, in <module>
  File "nibabel\volumeutils.pyc", line 22, in <module>
  File "nibabel\casting.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "nibabel\testing\__init__.pyc", line 35, in <module>
  File "nibabel\testing\np_features.pyc", line 19, in <module>
  File "nibabel\testing\np_features.pyc", line 12, in _memmap_after_ufunc
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Work\\PyToExe\\GUI\\v4\\dist\\lib2\\library.lib\\nibabel\\testing\\np_features.pyc'
```

When I ran the original Python script, no errors were raised with regard to importing [nibabel](http://nipy.org/nibabel/).

**In response to [@Sagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289812/sagar)'s comment:**

The import in the file Main_GUI.m:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import widgets
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib
import matplotlib as mpl 
import time
import os
```

Comment: Can you post your import lines from the main_GUI.py, please?

Comment: Is it a problem of version?

Answer (score 0):

there was a problem of compatibility between the modules versions (py2exe==0.6.9 and nibabel==2.2.0).
It works with py2exe 0.6.9 and nibabel 2.1.0.